# Expanding Storage by adding a second server?

Tags: linux, storage

I don't know if this is possible "out of the box" but here goes:

I have a dedicated Linux server with a LAMP kind of installation. It is being used as a cloud storage. The server is slowly getting filled with files and I was wondering if I can just buy a second server and "Virtually mount" it to the web directory of the main server?! Does that even make sense?

Let's say directory /var/www/files is on Server1. Server1 HDD is 90% full.
Can I "mount" Server2 to Server1s /var/www/files and make my Server1 Apache "think" it has 10% from Server1 HDD & the additional from Server2?

Distro: Debian 7, would be the same DC, 1gbps conntection, Traffic is not an issue.

Thanks for reading!! (Sorry if the nswer is obvious, couldn't find anything on google)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I "mount" Server2 to Server1s /var/www/files and make my Server1
>   Apache "think" it has 10% from Server1 HDD & the additional from
>   Server2?

Yes and no. You'd need to mount it to something like `/var/www/files2`. You can't just magically add storage to `/var/www/files` without expanding the filesystem (and underlying block storage).

Look into NFS. It is the canonical way to export storage from one linux server and present it to another.

Honestly, though, just upgrade the storage on your server. That will be the most reliable, least complex solution going forward.

Comment: I will look into that.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, didn't know "enter" submits the reply. The issue here is that my main server already has 2TB of storage and my file script saves to that one directory. If i created files2 that would mean all links to files1 would break. I want to be able to add server as my project grows and not think about upgrading the server and copy-pasting every few weeks. Any 3rd party solution?

Comment: Cluster/distributed filesystems are available (GlusterFS, Ceph, etc.), but they're not a panacea. They're difficult to set up right, complex to maintain, and honestly, it would be foolish for someone with your experience level to take on. Perhaps consider re-architecting your application to either store files in Amazon S3 or alternatively, to use some sort of a hash-based directory tree to store files. This would allow you to split storage between servers using NFS.